# Calculate Difference Between Two Time Periods

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

1). When I send input `startTimeString = "10:00 pm"` and `endTimeString = "4:00am"` then the answer should be `360 minutes`

2). When I send input `startTimeString = "10:00 am"` and `endTimeString = "6:00pm"` then the answer should be `480 minutes`

---

Here Is the method and this method is fail with this input `startTimeString = "10:00 pm"` and `endTimeString = "4:00am"`

```
    func differenceStartAndEndTime(startTimeString: String?, endTimeString: String?) -> Int {
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
       guard let startTime = dateFormatter.date(from: startTimeString ?? "0:00 am"), let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: endTimeString ?? "0:00 am") else {
           return 0
       }
       let minutes = Int(endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime) / 60)
       print("Here Is The Hours ~ \(minutes/60)")
       print("Here Is The Minutes ~ \(minutes%60)")

       return minutes > 0 ? minutes : 0
   }
```

Comment: You should check if `endTime` is bigger than `startTime`. if not, add it "1 day". Side note, adding 3600*24 to it works in most of the case, but it's not clean, You won't have daylight save changes, because a day is not necessary 24h...

Comment: yes, Thank-you for hint

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments just check if the end date is less than the start date and if true add a day to the end date. Regarding the timezone issues just make sure to set the date formatter's default date for the current date. besides those issues your method as it is will create a new date formatter every time you call this property. You can avoid that declaring the date formatter as static:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let time: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
func differenceStartAndEndTime(start: String, end: String) -> Int {
    Formatter.time.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    guard let startTime = Formatter.time.date(from: start),
          var endTime = Formatter.time.date(from: end) else {
          return 0
    }
    if endTime < startTime {
        endTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: endTime)!
    }
    let minutes = Int(endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime) / 60)
    print("Here Is The Hours:", minutes / 60)
    print("Here Is The Minutes:", minutes % 60)
    return minutes
}
```

---

```
differenceStartAndEndTime(start: "2:00 am", end: "6:00 am")  // 240
differenceStartAndEndTime(start: "10:00 pm", end: "4:00 am") // 360
differenceStartAndEndTime(start: "10:00 pm", end: "6:00 am") // 480
```

---

This will print:

> Here Is The Hours: 4
> Here Is The Minutes: 0
> Here Is The Hours: 6
> Here Is The Minutes: 0
> Here Is The Hours: 8
> Here Is The Minutes: 0